# Photoshop animation with Fuse: batch saving for different frames and options

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, photoshop-scripting

Is there a way to make a batch-script for automate saving (in .png files) each frame of the animation (Fuse character in Photoshop) with different character options, for example head location (as marked in the image below)? Unfortunetly, PS Actions are not working for 3d Fuse character options. The animation is made of preset body position (for example: Standard Idle). Thanks for your time!

What I would like to obtain is set of saved files for:
1st frame - Head position X=50
2nd frame - Head position X=49
3rd frame - Head position X=48 etc.

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Photoshop's Video Renderer?

1. Set each frame duration to 1 second.
2. File > Export > Video render
3. Select "Images sequence", "All images" and set the frequency to 1 image per second.
4. Click on Render, and each frame should be exported to an image.